# xslt: display cents value as currency correctly

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML fields which I need to process with XSLT:

```
<amount>9</amount>
...
<amount>200</amount>
...
```

9 is actually **9 cents** and 200 is actually **2 EUR**.
I need to transform these fields into this result:

```
0.09
2.00
```

I tried it using below code, but it doesn't work correctly:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(serviceFee, '###,###.##')" />
```

Is it possible to achieve this with XSLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(amount div 100, '#,##0.00')" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Doh, I totally forgot about math :)